# Customer Credit Applications For Invoicing Terms In NetSuite

Tags: web-apps, automation, finance

We currently have a (manual) method for customers to switch from prepaid to invoicing terms. It involves scoring them based on provided data, our research, and prior purchase history. This score then determines their credit limit. While there are some subjective elements, most of it is data-driven. The basics are, customers send us a PDF form, we verify the information, check references, check history with them, and then forward it for approval. However, this process isn't always consistently followed and creates challenges. I believe we can streamline and automate most of this within NetSuite to remove friction and put up some guardrails.

How are others handling customer credit applications for payment terms? Would NetSuite Cases with workflows be a viable in-built solution?

Comment: I am not sure if this is on topic. It askinf how to teeak an app rather than a recommendation for software.

Comment: @RohitGupta there is no app to do this, which is why I'm asking what others are using before I build something from scratch.